# two-dimensional if/then matrix

Tags: php, if-statement

I have to take action based on two variables (`$x` and `$y`).  The following meets those needs, but is not very readable, and it is not really obvious that `$x/$y` of `1/4` does the same thing as `$x/$y` of `5/3`.  From a readability and maintainability perspective, what is the best way to code this?  While I am specifically asking for a PHP solution, hopefully the solution could be extended to other languages such as JavaScript.

```
<?php
  switch($x) {
      case 1: case 2: case 3:
      switch($y) {
          case 1: case 2:
          doTask(1);
          break;
          case 3: case 4:
          doTask(2);
          break;
          default:
          doTask(3);
      }
      break;
      case 4: case 5:
      switch($y) {
          case 1: case 2: case 4:
          doTask(4);
          break;
          case 3:
          doTask(2);
          break;
          default:
          doTask(2);
      }
      break;
      default:
      switch($y) {
          case 1:
          doTask(6);
          break;
          case 2: case 3: case 4:
          doTask(2);
          break;
          default:
          doTask(3);
      }
  }
?>
```

Comment: What values `$x` and `$y` can have? If set is limited, then you could create combined variable `$xy` and use that in single `switch ($xy) { ...`

Comment: @MarkusLaire  `$x` and `$y` would only have limited values, however, I don't see how combining them into a single value would help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RiggsFolly  I only included the script to express intent.  I don't really think it should even be done with `switch` statements.  Instead, maybe an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you made an array to map this, it would work like this:

```
$task_x = [
   1  => [1 => 1, 2 => 1, 3 => 2, 4 => 2, 'd' => 3],
   2  => [1 => 1, 2 => 1, 3 => 2, 4 => 2, 'd' => 3],
   3  => [1 => 1, 2 => 1, 3 => 2, 4 => 2, 'd' => 3],
   4  => [1 => 4, 2 => 4, 3 => 2, 4 => 4, 'd' => 2],
   5  => [1 => 4, 2 => 4, 3 => 2, 4 => 4, 'd' => 2],
  'd' => [1 => 6, 2 => 2, 3 => 2, 4 => 2, 'd' => 3]
];

// PHP 7        
$task_y = $task_x[$x] ?? $task_x['d'];
$task_n = $task_y[$y] ?? $task_y['d'];

// or PHP 5
//$task_y = isset($task_x[$x]) ? $task_x[$x] : $task_x['d'];
//$task_n = isset($task_y[$y]) ? $task_y[$y] : $task_y['d'];

doTask($task_n);
```